# ¿Por qué no recibo las notificaciones de Stack Overflow en español por email o por su aplicación móvil?

Tags: soporte, notificaciones

No recibo las notificaciones a mi email o a mi móvil. He configurado mi perfil para recibir esas notificaciones por email, pero a pesar de eso no las recibo. He buscado en la bandeja de spam, correos no deseados y todas las bandejas de mi email, pero no encuentro ningún correo de Stack Overflow en español. Los únicos correos que recibo son los de trabajos recomendados de Stack Overflow.

[image: configuracion]

En el móvil me pasa lo mismo: a pesar de que tengo la opción de recibir notificaciones activa, estas no llegan. Y eso hace que tenga que entrar a la página o la aplicación cada vez que quiero saber si alguien ha respondido mi pregunta, ha comentado mi respuesta, he recibido un voto, etc...

[image: configuracion]

No sé si sea un error de configuración por mi parte, que aún no hayan implementado esa funcionalidad o que en realidad sea un bug. Pero por alguna razón no estoy recibiendo las notificaciones.

Comment: Me pasaba lo mismo, en mi caso fue debido al fabricante Huawei. De cierta forma este fabricante "protege" la recepción de notificaciones por default debido al ahorro de energía. Una vez que desprotegí las apps necesarias ya recibo las notificaciones. No sé qué fabricante sea el de tu móvil pero de igual forma deberías intentar algo así :)

Comment: El mio es un Samsung, pero al final todos son Android. Cual configuración realizaste para des proteger las apps?

Comment: En la sección de aplicaciones, seleccionas la app de Stack Exchange y ahí tienes una serie de configuraciones a realizar, como notificaciones, batería, espacio usado etc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Respondo a la parte de las notificaciones por correo electrónico

Hace poco se cambió la forma en que se gestionan los avisos. Se explica en [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906/209901)

Para el caso que comentas, aplicaría lo explicado en:

> **Community Milestones**: emails related to your bounties, reputation milestones and top new users. Because these emails are transactional in nature, all users are automatically opted in to them — but if you don't want them, you can easily opt out. If you qualify for swag, this is how we notify you — so you might want to keep this one turned on.

Mientras que la explicación dada en el perfil es un resumen algo malo:

> **Logros comunitarios**. Notificaciones sobre recompensas, reputación y más. Nótese: aveces se involucra el swag.

Con ello quiero decir que **no** recibirás emails cuando te voten una publicación. Si eso, los recibirás cuando superes algún hito que implique privilegios o pase algo con las recompensas (falta un día para que termine una que has abierto, por ejemplo).

Intenta replicar el error: habla con alguien para que te haga un *ping* en algún comentario, cierra la sesión y no entres durante X horas, X mayor que lo que tienes configurado. Si no recibes nada, reporta el error con estos datos: los moderadores pueden ver cuándo se te envía un error y podrían dar información útil.